# 1994 Silverado not accelerating past 35

Tags: chevrolet, automatic-transmission, silverado, transmission-fluid

I have a 1994 Chevy Silverado. On my way to work today my truck would not accelerate past 35 mph but was revving high rpm's. I stopped and checked my fluids and my ATF wasnt showing anything on the dipstick. I had just topped off all of my fluids 3 weeks ago. I went in the gas station and purchased a quart of atf fluid and it still didnt read anything on the dipstick. I was close to work so I drove it the remainder of the way here. I was fearful of putting too much atf fluid in there. How much should I use? Would the take care of the problem or am I looking at a more serious issue?

Comment: Have you recently had a fluid change or anything of that nature? Over tightening the pan can result in dramatic fluid loss as the gasket is only meant to be snug. Also check the dip stick grommet as it can crack over time with heat. Double check radiator fluid (if transmission cooler is internal to radiator)while at it because transmission fluid burns off way easier than oil does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How much should I use?

As much as you need to get it back up to operating level if you plan on driving it any more. If you don't get it up to the proper level, you'll be burning your soft parts up (clutches/bands) and risking the more expensive hard parts (planetaries, sun shell, sprag).

> Would the take care of the problem or am I looking at a more serious issue?

You are looking at something more serious. You need to figure out where the transmission fluid went to. More than likely you should be able to see where it's dripping from if you look under the truck. Obviously you're looking for the red Dexron fluid coming out somewhere. Since you lost so much so quickly, I'd suggest one of your seals is gone ... either front at the torque converter or at the back (hopefully) where the driveline goes into the transmission (or where the transfer connects if so equipped).

The issue will more than likely need to go to a shop to be fixed.

Comment: I would only add this must be done at operating temperature. That's proper for transmission fluid checking and top offs...

Comment: @Dee - Absolutely correct ... thanks for the assist! :D