# If trans fluid is low enough to cause issues, how long after adding new fluid should issues go away?

Tags: transmission-fluid

In regards to a recent bit of trouble I had with my cars transmission (Which sparked [This](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/47038/two-conflicting-mechanics-opinions-on-what-needs-to-be-fixed-which-one-should-i) question), in which on one occasion it wasn't moving in the reverse or drive gears when stopped and idling in gear, **at one point I'd discovered the car was low on ATF**.

I'd added half a quart, which brought the car back up to full on the dipstick.

I tried driving the car around the parking lot at various times throughout the rest of the day, after having added that fluid, but the issues that I was having  didn't go away until the next morning when I drove the car into the shop and had actually taken it a good few miles down the road at normal speeds. It hasn't shown problems since, and it's now been a few days.

Because of how long it had taken for the symptoms i was seeing go away, I'm pretty sure that the issues that I had aren't related to the fact that I was half a quart low on fluid.

However, I would like to know, for future reference at least, **if you had symptoms of low transmission fluid, how long after adding fluid should it take for those symptoms to go away?** Does a car need to run for a certain amount of time for the new fluid to circulate through all of the transmission components, etc?

I'm asking because in the future, if I run into a similar set of circumstances with a different car, i'd like to actually know how long after adding fluid, if a trans problem continued, I should wait before dismissing the possibility that it was a fluid issue and moving onward to checking for other possible causes.

Because that's not something I really know currently, after this happened recently, I found myself going out to the car several times throughout the evening to start it up and see if anything had changed, every hour or so after I'd added fluid.

Comment: * of course if you were low enough to cause overheating, you'd have some issues that didn't go away, but when I say 'issues' or 'symptoms' of being low on fluid I mean things like gear slipping, loss of power, etc.

Comment: and this : https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/25030/1994-silverado-not-accelerating-past-35?rq=1

Comment: @SolarMike this is not an 'exact' duplicate of the other question - one question asks how low your fluid would have to get to cause issues, the other asks how long it would take for those issues to go away. Those are two very different questions, and I feel like I've made what's being asked quite clear in the two posts.